# Error converting Varchar to Decimal SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a staging table loaded with data from a SAS dataset containing 5M records. All the columns are `varchar`. I am trying to convert a couple of columns to `decimal(32,10)`. But it generates an error. I tried cast, I tried convert and even splitting the data up before and after decimal - same result.

I looked at the `IsNumeric` flag of the column and there are 0 records <> 1 meaning the data is numeric.

```
case 
   when wtd_count = '.' THEN NULL
   when wtd_count = '' THEN NULL
   else convert(decimal(32, 10), wtd_count) 
end
```

Error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 99
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

So I'm wondering what else I can do to convert the data to decimal? Any idea?
Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be Decimal?  How about Val, or Long?  I'm assuming you want the value to be a number?

Comment: You obviously have at least one value in that table that is not able to be converted to a decimal. Take a look at TRY_PARSE (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx) if you are on 2012 or newer.

Comment: Thank you for your responses @Sean Lange.  Cannot use Try_Parse since I'm on Sql server 11.0.x.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Leptonator. Converting to Numeric (32,10) works. Just not to Decimal (32,10). Not sure why this would be the case.

Comment: you could try running the data through a cursor so that it goes record by record or try batching it up in chunks of a thousand records so that you can figure out the specific data that is causing your problem.  The following statement runs in SQL 2014, so it is a valid precision and scale.
    SELECT CAST('7.2' AS DECIMAL(32,10))

Comment: Why not convert it in SAS before loading it as a character string into the database? `input(wtd_count,32.)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are in SQL Server 2012 and above try to use try_parse or try_convert

Answer (score 0):

`ISNUMERIC` is not reliable for what you're doing. It will flag values with things like monetary symbols and commas in them as valid.

It seems quite likely that there is some non-numeric data present. `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_PARSE` are your friend here. As an FYI, SQL Server version 11.0.x is SQL Server 2012, so you should be able to use these.

I also find it hard to believe that converting to numeric works, but not decimal. I can find no information that suggests the actual implementation of these two data types is different, and as such neither should work.

I would do some more in depth analysis of your data to make sure it looks like you're expecting it to.

Answer (score 0):

After read your case statement i suppose that you have coma separated values. I'm pretty sure that you should use: `CONVERT(DECIMAL(32,10),REPLACE(wtd_count,',','.'))`